# Asynchronously upload images to Cloudinary using the Python API

Tags: python, asynchronous, syntax, parameters, cloudinary

I am trying to asynchronously upload images to Cloudinary using their Python API.

Their [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference) states the following is required to upload an image.

```
result = cloudinary.uploader.upload(file, **options)
```

Since, I would like to upload asynchronously, it appears I need to set the "async" option to True (also in the documentation).

> async (Boolean): Tells Cloudinary whether to perform the upload
>   request in the background (asynchronously). Default: false.

Since options has **, as explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters), I assume that the function accepts keyword arguments like so.

```
response = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(img, async=True)
```

However, when I run my script, I get the following error:

```
  File "async_upload.py", line 16
    response = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(img, async=True)
                                                         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**How do I upload multiple images asynchronously in Cloudinary?**

Comment: `async` is a reserved Python keyword now. The API lib seems to be older than that.

Comment: @KlausD. ahhhhhh that makes a lot of sense! Hmmm...I wonder what I should use instead :L

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific Cloudinary method.  You can use asyncio to upload asynchronously. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-guide-to-asynchronous-programming-in-python-with-asyncio-232e2afa44f6

Comment: I believe cloudinary.uploader.upload(img) without the async flag is a blocking function therefore using asyncio with the synchronous function call will not lead to any performance improvement over my existing synchronous solution.